# Argument stopped working

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using [ComplexHeatmap](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ComplexHeatmap.html) package for transcriptomic analyses and all of a sudden,  `row_labels` and `column_labels` as well as `heatmap_width` and `heatmap_height` stopped being recognized as arguments of the function Heatmap:

actual Heatmap

```
Heatmap(matrix [RowFunctionOrder,ColumnImposedOrder],
        col = colgrad,
        show_column_names = F,
        cluster_columns = FALSE,
        cluster_rows = FALSE,
        row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize=7),
        heatmap_width=1,
        heatmap_height = 1, 
        row_labels =  rnaseqMatrix$Protein.ID,
        bottom_annotation = Column_ha
        )
#creating a column annotation

Column_ha = HeatmapAnnotation(condition = colnames(matrix),condition = runif(30), col = list(condition=Colcolour), show_legend = FALSE).


*Error in Heatmap(matrix[RowFunctionOrder, ColumnImposedOrder], col = colgrad,  : 
  unused arguments (heatmap_width = 1, heatmap_height = 1, row_labels = rnaseqMatrix$Protein.ID)*.
```

this code was perfectly working this morning, I do not understand why suddenly the arguments were not valid anymore. they also seem to have disappeared from the help menu. this event followed a bug where I was receiving messaged saying the `help(ComplexHeatmap) could't be update.` this messages started appearing when I started typing arguments.

Comment: Hello Jordan, my best guess is that you have loaded a different package that has masked the original `Heatmap` function from `ComplexHeatmap` package. Does you have the same problem when you start a new R session and load only `ComplexHeatmap` package?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `sessionInfo()`. Also, try using `ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap()` instead of just `Heatmap()` - that should tell you if you're running into what @KamilSJaron is talking about.